# HttpOnly always set to true on cookie I add

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I have a .NET web application, where I have some custom code to store an auth token in a cookie:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[AuthTokenName] == null)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = new HttpCookie(AuthTokenName);
    authCookie.HttpOnly = false;
    authCookie.Value = result.AccessToken;
    authCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

    // tried both of these methods
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendCookie(authCookie);
    //HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);
}
else
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[AuthTokenName].Value = result.AccessToken;
}
```

I need to access the cookie on the client side through javascript, so `HttpOnly` needs to be `false`. I'm specifically setting `HttpOnly` to `false`, but my JS can't access the token, and that's because when I look at my browser cookies, `HttpOnly` is set to `true`

[image]

Am I setting the cookie wrong?

Comment: Do you call the code from web form or from web method ? could write more information to help to reproduce the situation

Comment: Did you try to remove the cookie in the browser and try the code again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following configuration in your web.config under system.web

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="false" requireSSL="false" />
```